# Changing a div position relative ,overlappingjquery,jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have this fiddle with me by pressing 'go' button it generate a new draggable element.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8uZ/5/
I want to change this fiddle in such a way that when the user clicks the go button the new div should created overlap on first div or in more easy way that new div position be on top left corner. Every new generated div should be in top-left corner and doesnot matter if its overlap. Jquery-ui dynamically give its relative i have tried some css top left property for new div but it is not giving correct results. Please help me in solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/Ty8uZ/29/

```
.ui-draggable {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```